# This thing comes up whenever I try to deploy a my war file in WildFly. I am new to this

Tags: wildfly, war

> Cannot upload deployment: {"WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => undefined,"WFLYCTL0288: One or more services were unable to start due to one or more indirect dependencies not being available." => {"Services that were unable to start:" => ["jboss.deployment.unit.\"bookstore-back.war\".PARSE"],"Services that may be the cause:" => ["jboss.remoting.remotingConnectorInfoService.http-remoting-connector"]}}

Comment: This isn't enough to go on.  There is another error, likely with a stack trace pointing to the real problem.  Can you take a look and post more?

Comment: This usually means that one of your beans is trying to get a hold of a dependency (maybe another bean) that was not injected, OR it may mean that your project relies on some jar(s) that are missing. Please post more info, with all your code.

Answer (score 1):

When the container detects changes and tries to deploy a web app, This will usually occur most likely because one of your beans is trying to get a hold of a dependency (maybe another bean) that was not injected, OR it may mean that your project relies on some jar(s) that are missing. Please post more info, with all your code.